# How to parse and interpret "Si è lasciato sfuggire il nome"?

Tags: grammar

> ***Si è lasciato sfuggire il nome.*** --- {He revealed / let slip the name (by accident).}

For the sake of clarity, can I interpret this sentence as:

> Lui è lasciato X + il nome gli è sfuggito di bocca.

Also: Do you need to use the auxiliary "è" before "lasciato" because "sfuggire" is an intransitive verb that takes the auxiliary "essere"? If you replace "sfuggire" with a transitive verb, then do you need to use the auxiliary "avere" instead before "lasciato"?

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean by “Lui è lasciato X + il nome si è sfuggito di bocca”, which is not how I'd decompose the sentence, but the second part should be “il nome gli è sfuggito di bocca” (since now the subject is the name, rather than “he”, so the pronoun isn't a reflexive pronoun anymore).

Comment: @DaG Hi. It's been just a week since I started learning Italian, so I didn't know the word "gli/to him". :) Yes, your paraphrase fits the bill.

Comment: We need the auxiliary "è" before "lasciato" because the verb is "lasciarsi", a reflexive verb. All reflexive verbs need the auxiliary "essere".

Comment: The meaning would be the same as "Ha lasciato che il nome gli sfuggisse di bocca" (literal translation: "He/she let the name get away from his/her mouth"), but "Si è lasciato sfuggire il nome" is a more idiomatic way of saying that.